# How to use AngularJS ui-router to build same URL as <ui-sref> in controller instead of HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularJS's ui-router in my webapp. I have a state that looks like this:

```
  $stateProvider.state('mystate',
    {
      url: '/mystate/{id:int}/:slug',
      params: {
        slug: {value: null, squash: true}
      },
      templateUrl: 'partials/mystate.html',
      controller: 'MyStateCtrl'
    }
  );
```

I can link to this state in my view like this:

```
<a ui-sref="mystate({id: 4, slug: 'myslug'})">Hello World</a>
```

It converts it to the following URL: `/mystate/4/myslug/`

I want to build the same URL that `ui-sref` produces, but I want it inside `MyStateCtrl`. How do I do that? In the controller, I have access to  `$stateParams.id` and `$stateParams.slug`. But what function do I need to call to convert them to that URL?

**EDIT**: Please note: I do not want to ***go*** to the resultant URL. I just want to ***have*** it for later use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a url just like you ui-sref with the function `$state.href()`. You just need to provide the route and its params that you can get from `$stateParams`.

```
e.g. expect($state.href("about.person", { person: "bob" })).toEqual("/about/bob");
```

So in your case:

```
$state.href("mystate", { id: $stateParams.id, slug: $stateParams.slug });
```

And here is the documentation - [$state.href()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#statehrefstateorname--params--options)

Answer (score 1):

You can inject $state as a dependency to MyStateCtrl and use `$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])` function for navigating to target URL.

For example:

```
class MainController {

  constructor($scope, $state) {
    'ngInject';

    this.scope = $scope;
    this.state = $state;

   }

   navigateToAState() {
     this.state.go('mystate',{id: 4, slug: 'myslug'})
   }
 }

 export default MainController;
```

**Detail Reference:**
  [`$state.go(to \[, toParams\] \[, options\])`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)

Comment: Thanks! What if I don't want to redirect to that state? I just want to have the URL for some other purpose. Can I do it without `$state.go()`?

Comment: @SaqibAli, yes $state.go will freely take you to the url you want as it identifies a state by given state name.

Comment: I don't want to **go** to that URL. I just want to store that URL and use it for something else. How can I do that??

Comment: @SaqibAli, could plz edit your question to reflect what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Edited. Thanks. I also found the answer in the link that Vipin Jain posted: `$state.href()`

Answer (score 1):

A url generation method that returns the compiled url for the given state populated with the given params.

```
Example : expect($state.href("about.person", { person: "bob" })).toEqual("/about/bob");
```

you can use this

`$state.href ('mystate',{id: 4, slug: 'myslug'});`

[See This link for more help](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Comment: Thanks! What if I don't want to redirect to that state? I just want to have the URL for some other purpose. Can I do it without `$state.go()`?

Comment: Yup. You can use for other purpose. i have send a link for it you can see all options http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state . Look it if any problem add comment

Comment: Thanks! I found what I needed at that link: `$state.href()`.